# Reading Registry values

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function readJREValue() {
  document.write("<b>Java Runtime Environment properties of your computer : </b>")
  document.write("<br>")
                var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                var value = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\\Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\BrowserJavaVersion");
  document.write("Your JRE Browser Version Is: " + value);
  document.write("<br>");
            };


        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript: readJREValue()">

    </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine when I run it from my desktop. But when I am trying to run from my localhost no out will come..

Comment: Of course not. What would happen if a website did this and was suddenly able to read everybodies registry values? Try to add the site as a "trusted site".

Comment: can u pls say what error or warnings u got?? as this is completely impossible

Comment: No error no output or when i use to read from dll says undefine